# Resources not found after deploying with GitHub pages

Tags: webpack, deployment, github-pages

I've forked [this](https://github.com/bchiang7/v4) repository and then proceeded to build and deploy it as suggested but I cannot start correctly the web site.

The passes I've followed are:

1. git cloned the repo
2. Moved in the folder and executed without any problem: `npm install -g yarn`
3. Executed: `yarn`
4. Executed: `npm install -g gatsby-cli`
5. Executed: `npm install`
6. Executed: `gatsby build`
7. Executed: `npm run deploy` where deploy is defined as: `gatsby build && gh-pages -d public -b gh-pages`

These commands correctly build the project and create a new branch on the repository with the *public* folder which is the build foledr.

My repository is configured to use GitHub pages like this:

[image: GitHub settings]

but whenever I open the web site I can only see background color and opening console I see a few errors reaching resources:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () 
webpack-runtime-b79041fc2b38a6c91c6b.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
app-8f8fb0f08c61a13c61ac.js:1
[...]
```

---

I can correctly make changes to the repository and start it locally with `gatsby serve`. The only problem I have is with deployment, can someone figure out what's my problem with the info I provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GitHub Pages Site is published at `https://surveiior.github.io/surveiior.com/` and not `https://surveiior.github.io/`.
So, for example, 
You have used `/page-data/index/page-data.json` in the HTML code, which sends the request to [`https://surveiior.github.io/page-data/index/page-data.json`](https://surveiior.github.io/page-data/index/page-data.json), but the `json` file is published at [`https://surveiior.github.io/surveiior.com/page-data/index/page-data.json`](https://surveiior.github.io/surveiior.com/page-data/index/page-data.json).
You can use `./page-data/index/page-data.json` or `page-data/index/page-data.json` in the HTML code and it is where the file is hosted.
**In short, to make the file path correct, you can add a `.`[dot] before the slashes of every address that is showing Error 404, and it will show the correct file if the file path is correct.**

Comment: Thanks. I should've changed the deploy script in some way to allow it to generate index with different paths, I solved the problem by making my repository a user repository, in that way it automatically didn't include the repository name and the resource are exactly where he wants.

Comment: @SimoneLungarella what exactly you did to make your repository as a "user repository" on GitHub ?

Comment: I'm not really sure right now but should be enough calling the repository: username.github.io